# Trouble with setting machine key & forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, forms-authentication, machinekey

I'm creating a new project in .net 4.5 of an existing project that is using .net 3.5. The way it works is that they login through the landing site and on there they choose which of the two sites to go to. All the sites have a machine key set.

I have the sites set as this way

- a.site.com - Landing page
- b.site.com
- c.site.com

The .net 3.5 version of the app works, but I can not get the 4.5 version of the app to work. It logs me in on the landing page, but every time I go to site b or c, it redirects me back to the login page. I've checked the configurations in web config on all three apps and they are using the same machine key and form information. Here is the format config I am using.

```
        <machineKey validationKey="ZZZ" decryptionKey="YYY" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".FormName" loginUrl="http://a.site.com/login.htm" defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="15" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="site.com" />
    </authentication>
```

I have read there are issues on this site with the machine key, but those seem to apply with different apps running different .net versions. The new apps I am using are running the same .net version and are hosted on Microsoft Server 2008. I am not sure what configuration/setting I'm missing that is causing this. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

**UPDATE :**

Here was the code i was using :

Dim MyGuid As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()

```
            Dim sSSO_ID As String = Guests.AddSSOIDForDirectLogin(iGuestID, MyGuid.ToString)

            ' first write the authentication cookie to 
            ' the machine so we know the user is sSSO_ID
            'FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sSSO_ID, False)

            Dim sPersistentCookie As Boolean = False

            Dim t As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, sSSO_ID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), sPersistentCookie, sSSO_ID.ToString, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
            Dim eTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(t)
            Dim c As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, eTicket)

            If sPersistentCookie = True Then
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3)
            End If


            Response.Cookies.Add(c)
```

Turns out I commented out SetAuthCookie of which set the domain. The forms authentication ticket I created was not setting the domain. Isn't SetAuthCookie similar to that of creating the forms authentication ticket, so would both be necessary? It would be simply just be adding c.Domain="site.com" before adding the cookie